# Stackdriver multi-channel logging with Symfony/Monolog and Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, symfony4, monolog

is there a current method to do some multi-channel logging of an Symfony application running on Kubernetes in Google Cloud and having the log channel data collected in Googles Stackdriver?

I've found an older solution under [Google Cloud Stackdriver and monolog Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676196/google-cloud-stackdriver-and-monolog-symfony) but it seems to be a bit legacy regarding Symfony and Google Cloud library versions.

I need the multiple channels for context related logging and I'd like to have an easy filter mechanism in the Google Console Logging (if it's possible to do it this way) so my idea was to use the Monolog channels like I use it on local development environment or old-fashioned hosting projects.

Comment: Hello. Could you clarify if you are looking for solutions to send logs from the `Symfony` to the  `Stackdriver` or are you looking for ways to search the Stackdriver logs?

Comment: Hi @DawidKruk, thanks for asking.

I was looking for a solution to send logging data of multiple channels to the `Stackdriver` system. Finally I think I got a solution by sending all channels to `php://stdout` and formatting the logging data as JSON using `formatter: 'Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter'`. So I was able to use the `Stackdriver` build-in filter/query language to filter my wanted channels.